# SAS: How to subset a dataset with changing the name of entities?

Tags: csv, sas

I have a given data set in SAS:

```
Variable  Level    Frequency  Percent
  Var1      B         941      29.46
  Var1      C         820      25.67
  Var2    Unknown     813      25.45
  Var2      E         756      23.67
  Var3      I         930      29.12
  Var3    Unknown     750      23.48
```

for every variable the first coming variable is the maximum value and the next level is the second maximum value. That is for Var1, Level - B is the maximum Value and C is the second maximum value. I want that for every Maximum value if the Level is Unknown then the second maximum value becomes the maximum value. To illustrate the final output should be:

```
Variable  Level   Max_Value  Percent
  Var1      B        941      29.46
  Var2      E        756      23.67
  Var3      I        930      29.12
```

i think i have to subset the data anyhow and then use `PROC TRANSPOSE` in order to get the data i require. Can anybody help me with the subsetting and transposing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be asking a question for each stage of your code (based on what you've asked for previously).  It may be better if you start off with your original data and what the final output should look like, as it's possible the manipulation asked for here could be best done in an earlier step.  At the very least, show the full code you currently have to get to this stage

Comment: @Keith i understand it perfectly. Thanks for pointing out. will keep it in mind for future. Actually if i have asked all at once then the problem can be more complex and i would be getting more downvotes for making the problem un-explainable. but well every suggestion has learning. Thanks much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to sort by descending freq and keep first.variable, while discarding level eq: 'U'.  You can get the sort with PROC FREQ and then it is just another step to subset.

```
title;
data exp;
   infile cards dsd firstobs=2;
   input Policy_Number (var1-var3) ($) Exposure;
   'arbitrary name 243'n = rank(first(var1));
   arbitraryname4 = rantbl(123,.4);
   arbitraryname36 = rank(first(var3));
   cards;
Policy_Number,var1,var2,var3,Exposure
1,B,H,J,191
2,B,F,Unknown,174
3,C,Unknown,I,153
4,B,G,L,192
5,Unknown,E,Unknown,184
6,D,E,K,113
7,C,Unknown,I,140
8,A,H,I,133
9,C,F,I,194
10,Unknown,G,Unknown,105
11,B,H,L,172
12,A,Unknown,I,198
13,D,E,K,155
14,Unknown,G,K,177
15,B,H,Unknown,100
16,D,Unknown,J,176
17,B,E,I,112
18,Unknown,E,J,192
19,C,Unknown,K,146
20,C,G,Unknown,187
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=exp(obs=0 drop=policy_number exposure) out=varlist;
   var _all_;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
Proc sql noprint; 
   select nliteral(_name_) into :classvars separated by ' ' from varlist;
   quit;
%put NOTE: &=classvars;
ods select none;
proc freq data=exp order=freq;
   tables &classvars / nocum;
   weight exposure;
   ods output onewayfreqs=freqs;
   run;
ods select all;

data freqs(keep=Variable Levels Frequency Percent);
   length Variable $32 Levels $64;
   set freqs;
   variable = substr(table,6);
   levels = coalesceC(of F_:);
   run;
data maxsansunk;
   set freqs;
   where levels ne: 'U';
   by variable notsorted;
   if first.variable;
   rename Frequency=Max_Value;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]